# Where do I find hexadecimal value for MS-word Accent blue colour?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, colors, hexadecimal

The title says it all, googled but to no avail.
where do I find the hexadecimal value of the following colour:

**Blue Accent 1** (see image)

Does anyone know a source for word document colours, can the hexa codes be found in the document itself?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Adding the answer to the question after another answer & several back & both comments just confuses the whole issue. Please use the answer space for answers, not the question space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it on MAC. Click on more colours, then colour sliders and use the pen tool for getting the colour, your code will show after you select that colour.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To find the color in hexadecimal, do the following:

1. Created a text, and highlight it.
2. Set it color, in your case blue accent.
3. Click on the arrow next to the font color and select more color.

[image: IMG:]

4. The hex value of the color will be shown. In your case, the hex value of blue accent is `4472C4`.

[image: IMG:]

in case your version does not have the hex values shown, you can find RGB to hex converter online. Or just type `rgb to hex` on Google search; a color picker will appear. Enter the RGB values separated by commas an spaces. It will show their hex values. See the second image below from Google search. OR even simpler, use the calculator app of your PC, set it to programmer, enter each RGB value individually in decimal. Depending on your OS, you should see the hex value or click on hex button/radiobox to show the value.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I've got 'Word for Office 365' v16.0.11929.20836 64-bit (Version 1908) & that Hex field isn't showing. It was added in O365 Version 2003: https://blog-insider.office.com/2020/02/19/hex-color-values-in-color-picker/

Comment: @gregg You can then use an hex converter to convert the RGB numbers.

Comment: The answer above gives me the basic codes to use

Comment: @gregg See edit.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio cannot find either of these colour pickers, using MS word 16.36 for MAC OS, could be because of that. Anyhow, tnx for the hexacode,

Comment: @eugene_sunic The second image is from Google search RGB to hex converter. What do you see when you click More options?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, found it, look at the EDITED question